# Kotlin File.copyTo throws FileAlreadyExistsException with overwrite set to true

Tags: android, file, kotlin, overwrite

I am developing an application which has some specific requirements, one of these is to log every single action performed on the app:

1. Action performed by the user
2. Log the action with Timber
3. Append that row to a log file in the device's external storage (device mass storage)
4. Update the copy of that file in the removable external storage (SD card)

Whenever an action is performed I use `Timber.i("log message")` and I have overridden the `log(Int, String, String, Throwable)` method to where I do the other things:

```
override fun log(priority: Int, tag: String?, message: String, t: Throwable?) {
    if (priority == Log.INFO) {
        appendToLog(message);
    }
}
```

and the `appendToLog(String)` is:

```
private fun appendToLog(message: String) {
    // skipping the unnecessary code which transforms some info in a string, this works fine
    val log = LogData(...)

    // pathManager.getLogFile() returns a File and works
    val fw = FileWriter(pathManager.getLogFile(),true)
    // log.checksum() and log.encrypt() return a String, this works fine
    val checksum = log.checksum()
    val encrypted = log.encrypt()
    fw.write(encrypted.plus("--!").plus(checksum))
    fw.close()


    // copying log file to sd
    pathManager.getLogFile()
        .copyTo(pathManager.getSdLogFile(), true) // the exception is thrown here

}
```

The exception that is thrown is as follows, can't add other details of this for legal reasons, this is all the revelant information of the exception

```
kotlin.io.FileAlreadyExistsException:
my/file/path -> my/file/path: The destination file already exists
```

I read [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.1.3/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/io/files/Utils.kt#L177) that this exception [is thrown](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/caa2d7a6ce80901f240227ecd4819713c064a2a8/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/io/files/Utils.kt#L186) only if the destination file already exists and if overwrite `false`, but I have set it as `true`.

Has anybody experienced this? How can I get it to work?

**#Note:**
I know that this may be out of the Android standards/guidelines, this is not a common application but a product designed and developed to meet the customer specifications.

Comment: I believe that you asked this previously, but deleted your question and my comments. As I recall from my previous comments, you do not have read/write access to arbitrary locations on removable storage. If you do not have write access to this location, that would trigger the behavior outlined by Kiskae in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56633885/115145).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to the exact code you linked:

`val stillExists = if (!overwrite) true else !target.delete()`

It will still throw that exception when `overwrite` is true and [`File#delete`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete()) returns false, indicating it was unable to delete the target file. This can have multiple reasons but these are the most common ones:

1. the target file is a directory and it still contains files.
2. some other process has the file opened, holding its lock and preventing mutations.

The `File#delete` javadoc refers to the `Files#delete` method if you want better better information on the reason for a delete failure, manually calling it before calling `File.copyTo` would allow you to identify the reason for the failure.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Kotlin 1.3.60 `File.copyTo` is going to report a distinct error message if `overwrite` flag was true and deleting the target file has failed:

`$from -> $to: Tried to overwrite the destination, but failed to delete it.`

See [KT-27545](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27545) for details.